# Как повесить слушатель на кнопку send?

Tags: ios, swift

У меня на клавиатуре на IPAD, есть кнопка SEND, но при нажатии на неё ничего не случается. Как повесить слушатель на эту кнопку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего это кнопка объекта `UITextField()`.

Вам необходимо подписаться на делегат вашего `UITextField()`, делегатом может быть любой класс (но обычно делегатом делают контроллер на котором находится `UITextField()`)

```
//Пример
textField.delegate = self
```

Дальше, тот класс который вы назначили делегат надо подписать на протокол `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
//Пример
class YourClass: UITextFieldDelegate
```

После чего необходимо реализовать метод нажатия кнопки `Send`

```
//Пример
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    //Do something
    return true
}
```

Если же объект у вас не UITextField(), а UITextView() то реализация повторяется с новым классом, кроме метода делегата, метод должен быть следующим.

```
 //Пример
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло